# content restrictions on Android?

Tags: android

I cannot find any articles on the content restrictions for developing on Andriod. Are there any? My client wants to make an app that contains 'strong adult language' for sexual position as well as potentially adult imagery.

Comment: You mean for listing your app on the Android market? You don't need any approval from Google to develop and distribute an application outside of the market.

Answer (score 3):

From the "[Android Market Content Policy for Developers](http://www.android.com/market/terms/developer-content-policy.html)":

> Developers should not upload or otherwise make available applications or any other materials that display (via text, images, video or other media) or link to:
>
> [...]
>
> - any material not suitable for persons under 18.
> - pornography, obscenity, nudity or sexual activity.

There is obviously a question as to how strongly these terms are enforced, but what you are describing clearly is not officially allowed.  It's possible to distribute apps for Android outside the official market, and you may want to have a look at [Mikandi](http://www.mikandi.com) for an alternate adult-oriented market...

Answer (score 0):

There's a few adult based apps out there already, so I'm guessing that there aren't really any (at least not based on adult content).